# How do I insert an expiration time for a row in a column?

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

I am new to php/mysql. Using this example how do I insert an expiration time along with a row?

```
INSERT INTO ajaxfavourites (user, favid) VALUES ('$user', '$favid')
```

Let's say if I want both user and favid to expire in 30 days.

Comment: You can insert a timestamp column and create a background process that deletes (or flags as deleted) the row after 30 days `if(time() >= $yourTimeStamp + (846000 * 30) )`... Btw as it is now, your question is off-topic here, post what have you tried so far.

Comment: I didn't try much of anything yet. I googled it and couldn't find a reasonable answer. Basically it's a normal sql connection and one of the functions inserts in both user and favid. I am new to php so I thought I'd ask what are generic ways for doing this. I know it can be done using a timestamp, I am wondering if that's the route I want to go. How would you insert those rows with a timestamp and expiration assigned to them?

Comment: @ Cliff Burton So to insert I'd do something like INSERT
INTO    mytable (timestamp_field)
VALUES  (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) but how how do I create a background process? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @qwikad - I have not understood very well what you want to achieve, but when inserting `user` and `favid` you can insert the timsstamp too in the same query (I use the PHP `time()` function assigned to a variable, because while the script runs, the timestamp can change, but if you assign it to a variable at the top of your script you can use this variable everywhere in the script itself) -- A background process is a simple script that you want to automatically call at a current time, each day/hour. If your host allows background/timed scripts, you can find it in you control panel. ;)

Comment: I got this one figured out using the link to another similar post. Thanks everyone for your help!